# Calculus Derivatives In

Tags: calculus, derivatives, education

What is the derivative of the function h(x)=In(f(x))?
I know it would end up being a fraction but I am unsure

Comment: What is $\operatorname{In}(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

$h(x)=\ln (f(x))$

Applying Chain Rule:$$h'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$